# PHP申し込みフォームをGoogleスプレッドシートに自動入力

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

PHPの申し込みフォームに入力された内容をGoogleAppScriptを用いて、Googleスプレッドシートに自動入力するプログラムを作りたいと考えています。
下記方法でも構いませんし、他に最適な方法があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

申し込みフォームがあるPHP側の一番上にこちらを書き加えました。

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

    define('POST_URL', 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzU4OwOwY4DNMcDrnBCNguWGCyDGNVXU3tFa3-Kcg/exec');

    $post_data = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'hurigana' => $_POST['hurigana'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'tel' => $_POST['tel'],
        'juusyo' => $_POST['juusyo'],
        'company' => $_POST['company'],
        'other' => $_POST['other'],
        'hokenshinsei' => $_POST['hokenshinsei'],
        'rireki' => $_POST['rireki'],
        'date01' => $_POST['date01'],
        'date02' => $_POST['date02'],
        'date03' => $_POST['date03'],
        'date-comment' => $_POST['date-comment'],
        'txt' => $_POST['txt'],
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => POST_URL,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post_data),
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

GASの方ではこの二つの関数を記述しています。

```
function doPost(e) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('データ');
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var last_row = sheet.getLastRow(); 

    if(headers[0] === 'timestamp'){
        sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'));
    }

    for(var key in e.parameter){
        for(var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++){
            if(headers[i] === key){
                sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, i + 1).setValue(e.parameter[key]);
                break;
            } else if(headers.length === i + 1){
                var new_column = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
                sheet.getRange(1, new_column).setValue(key);
                sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, new_column).setValue(e.parameter[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function pushBtn(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('集計');

    var last_col = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
    var last_row = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    sheet.getRange(2,1,last_row,last_col).clear();

    last_row = sheet.getLastRow(); 

    var data_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('データ');
    var data_headers = data_sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, data_sheet.getLastColumn() -       1).getValues(); //headder取得
    var data_last_row = data_sheet.getLastRow(); 

    //開始日付終了日付行数をデータシートから取得
    var sobj = new Date(sheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue());
    var eobj = new Date(sheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue());
    eobj.setDate(eobj.getDate() + 1);
    var flg = false;
    var sdate_row, edate_row;

    for(var i = 0; i < data_last_row; i++){
        var tdate = data_sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1).getValue();
        var tobj = new Date(tdate);

        if(sobj < tobj && flg == false){
            sdate_row = i + 2;
            flg = true;
        }
        if(eobj  < tobj){
            edate_row = i + 1;
            break;
        }
        if(!edate_row){
            edate_row = data_last_row;
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < data_headers[0].length; i++){
        sheet.getRange(last_row + 1 + i, 1).setValue(data_headers[0][i]);
        var myCurrentArray = data_sheet.getRange(sdate_row,i + 2,edate_row,1).getValues();
        var counts = {};

        for(var c=0;c< myCurrentArray.length;c++) {
            //Logger.log(c);
            var key = myCurrentArray[c];
            counts[key] = (counts[key])? counts[key] + 1 : 1 ;
        }

        var t = 0;
        for (var k in counts) {
            if (k != '' && counts.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                var value = counts[k];
                sheet.getRange(last_row + 1 + i, t + 2).setValue(k + ':' + value);
                t++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

検証を重ねる中で、

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('データ');
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
```

の部分に不備があることが分かったのですが、解決方法が見つかりません。
手動でdoPost.gsを起動した場合、スプレッドシートのtimestampに日時が記入されていることは確認できました。
ですが、PHPの申し込みフォームを入力した場合、スプレッドシートに日時が記入されてないため、当該箇所に問題があることがわかりました。

この場合の解決方法、もしくは別の方法がありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: Web Appsの設定が`Execute the app as: Me`, `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous`であり、表示されているGAS側のスクリプトからスプレッドシート（`データ`シート）の1行目はヘッダ行として、`timestamp`と各プロパティのkey namesが設定されていることを想定します。もしもこの推測が正しい場合、表示されているスクリプトはPHPが実行されると日時データとともに送られてきた値がシートへアペンドされると思われます。そこで、これが直接の解決方法かどうかは分かりませんが、一度Web Appsを新しいバージョンとして再デプロイした後に再度PHPを実行すると、どのような結果が得られますでしょうか。

Comment: @Tanaike コメントをいただきありがとうございます。
仰る通り、スプレッドシートの１行目はヘッダ行としてtimestampと各namesを設定しています。

Execute the app as: Me 
Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous
に設定して、php内リンクを変更、申し込みフォームを実行しましたが、
スプレッドシートに反映されませんでした。

PHP内の記述に問題があるのか、GASの記述に問題があるのか続けて探ろうと思います。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。Web Appsの設定、スプレッドシートの状態について確認しました。質問内に表示されているPHPとGASのスクリプトの両方については特に問題ないと思います。PHPのスクリプトが実行されると、GAS側の`doPost`へデータが送られてスプレッドシートへ日時とデータを持った行が1行追加されます。ところで、ご返事からは新しいバージョンでWeb Appsを再デプロイしたかどうかについては読み取ることができませんでした。これについてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @Tanaike ご返事ありがとうございます。GASにおいて再度、公開→ウェブアプリケーションとして導入→Deproy ass a appにて上記設定＋ProjectVersion[New]でデプロイ、しております。"新しいバージョンで再デプロイ"というのはこちらの操作で問題ないでしょうか。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。返事の内容から再デプロイについては問題なさそうに思われます。その場合、表示されているスクリプトは問題なく動作すると思われます。今、テストとしてこちらでも実行したところ、問題なく動作しました。このテストでは、`$post_data`の各値はサンプルの値を用意しました。そこで、そちらの問題を正しく再現するための詳細なフローをお教えいただけないでしょうか。これにより、問題の再現を試みたいと思います。